# What is database /DBMS "patch access"?

Tags: database

Could not find this term very easily on google.

I assume it's the ability to patch a DBMS with an update without stopping service.

Is this correct?  If not, please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

jbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Patch Access** usually refers to a service to (preferrable easily) get access to relevant patches (for your dbms in this case).

For more information see:

- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3569941/Database-Security-and-Patches--Part-3.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Access_Control